# wrong product price in email invoice by woo commerce plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have used WooCommerce plugin for membership and to purchase a book or book an event.

But after checkout, it's showing wrong product price in invoice that user gets in his email. I have shared PDF screenshot in which the price showed is incorrect.

It should display **$89**, but it's showing **$0.00**.

Kindly help me to resolve it.

[image: PDF invoice after checkout in email]

Comment: do you have a plugin for this pdf?

Comment: which booking plugin are you using that you "**purchased a book or book an event**"? We can't understand.

Comment: There is no another plugin for pdf. All work is done by woo commerce only. Purchase a book and book an event is done by woo commerce only.